# Counting gradient using 2 columns array from external .dat file

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have got a .dat file with 2 columns and rows between 14000 to 36000 saved in file like below:

```
0.00   0.00
2.00   1.00
2.03   1.01
2.05   1.07
.
.
.
79.03  23.01
```

The 1st column is extension, the 2nd is strain. When I want to count gradient to designate Hooks Law of the plot, I use below code.

```
CCCCCC
      Program gradient
      REAL S(40000),E(40000),GRAD(40000,1)
      open(unit=300, file='Probka1A.dat', status='OLD')
      open(unit=321, file='result.out', status='unknown')
      write(321,400)
400   format('alfa')
260   DO 200 i=1, 40000
      read(300,30) S(i),E(i)
30    format(2F7.2)
      GRAD(i,1)=(S(i)-S(i-1))/(E(i)-E(i-1))
      write(321,777) GRAD(i,1)
777   Format(F7.2)
200   Continue
      END
```

But after I executed it I got the warning

```
PGFIO-F-231/formatted read/unit=300/error on data conversion.
 File name = Probka1A.dat    formatted, sequential access   record = 1
 In source file gradient1.f, at line number 9
```

What can I do to count gradient by this or other way in Fortran 77?

Comment: If you replace `read(300,30)` with `read(300,*)`, or prepend a space to each line, it's fine?

Comment: After use `read(300,*)` I got the warning: 
`PGFIO-F-217/list-directed read/unit=300/attempt to read past end of file.
 File name = Probka1A.dat    formatted, sequential access   record = 14398
 In source file gradient1.f, at line number 9`

Answer (score 1):

You are reading from file without checking for the end of the file. Your code should be like this:

```
260   DO 200 i=1, 40000
      read(300,*,ERR=400,END=400) S(i),E(i)
      if (i>1) then
          GRAD(i-1,1)=(S(i)-S(i-1))/(E(i)-E(i-1))
          write(321,777) GRAD(i-1,1)
      end if
777   Format(F7.2)
200   Continue
400   continue
```

Comment: After I execute this i got this warning:
`/tmp/pgf77anqawnGT_Gd.o: In function gradient':
/mnt/auto/people/plgkamilwalus/fortran/Gryn/Do fortranu/./gradient1.f:13: undefined reference to .LB1_351'`

Comment: Which line is number 13?

Comment: `400 exit`    -> is line 13

Comment: It's almost working properly but in result.out I got:
`alfa
NaN
NaN
  NaN
  NaN
  NaN
  NaN
  NaN
  NaN
  NaN
  NaN
  NaN
  NaN.........`

I read about NaN and it's something wrong with "this is not a number".

Comment: In the line with GRAD you have `i-1`, so the when `i=1`, your index will be 0, below the lower limit. Make a condition `if (i>1) then ...`. (See edited answer)

Comment: Another way instead of err or end is to use iostat in the read statement.  The advantage is you don't need to use line numbers which are outdated like f77.  There are examples of iostat online, it's worth a look.